StatefulShellRoute navigation with Universal Back Button
This is my go route path
             => /
             => /login
             => /camera
             => /home
             =>   /home/post
             =>     /home/post/upload
             => /search

I am using StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack for Home Page and Search Page, my use case is on /home/post/upload I am going to push the /camera because upload have an option to take a photo rather than uploading a file.
My expected behavior is after pushing /camera I should be able to go back to /home/post/upload -> /home/post/ -> /home.
But what's happening is after pushing /camera I'm only able to go back to /home/post/upload

Android Universal Back Button Behavior:

/camera -> /home/post/upload -> It closes the application


iOS Universal Back Button Behavior:

/camera -> /home/post/upload -> Nothing happens



Please keep in mind that the back button in Scaffold is still working as intended
Calling context.pop() programmatically still works as intended
